# Insert multiple rows from pyspark to cosmosdb

Tags: pyspark, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to insert more than one row to dataframe in pyspark. This is my code:

First I import the packages:

```
import pydocumentdb
from pydocumentdb import document_client
from pydocumentdb import documents
```

Then, I define the connectionPolicy:

```
connectionPolicy = documents.ConnectionPolicy()
connectionPolicy.EnableEndpointDiscovery
connectionPolicy.PreferredLocations = {"Western Europe"}
```

The credentials:

```
masterKey = 'yourmasterkey'
host = 'https://testcosmosdbasdada.documents.azure.com:443/'
client = document_client.DocumentClient(host,{'masterKey': masterKey}, connectionPolicy)
```

Then I define a name of a database and a collection:

```
databaseId = 'pruebadb'
collectionId = 'collection1'

dbLink = 'dbs/' + databaseId
collLink = dbLink + '/colls/' + collectionId
```

Note: I should create a database and a collection with this names in Azure suite.
Then I can use or CreateDocument or UpsertDocument. I am going to use UpsertDocument.

```
client.UpsertDocument(collLink,{'attribute1': 4}, options=None)
```

This works! As you see in documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/pydocumentdb/pydocumentdb.document_client.documentclient?view=azure-python#upsertdocument

However I don't know how to insert some rows at once. These proofs do not work:

1)

```
client.UpsertDocument(collLink,[{'attribute1': 4},{'attribute1': 2}], options=None)
```

'list' object has no attribute 'get'

2)

```
client.UpsertDocument(collLink,[{'attribute1': 4},{'attribute1': 2}], options=None)
```

'list' object has no attribute 'get'

3)

```
df = spark.read.csv('/FileStore/tables/points.csv', sep=';', header=True)
client.UpsertDocument(collLink, df, options=None)
```

'list' object has no attribute 'get'

These proofs do not work because I need a dict as second argument of UpsertDocument().

There are any function of pydocumentdb or another python library in order to do that?

How is the best performance method to insert data from a dataframe to CosmosDB with pyspark?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataFrameWriter` API offered by Spark MongoDB connector for this instead of relying on the CosmosDB API.

The below code should work:

```
df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")\
        .option("uri", "<CosmosDB URI>")\
        .option("database","CosmosDB Database Name")\
        .option("collection","CosmosDB Collection Name")\
        .mode("append").save()
```

You would be needed to add the Spark-MongoDB connector to your classpath either by using `--jars` argument or `--packages` argument in your spark-submit command.

Ex: `spark-submit --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.0.0 <YOUR_SRC_FILE>.py`

More on DataFrameWriter API can be found at: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Sivaprasanna Sethuraman, I have been investigating. It is not necessary use MongoDB. Finally I have found: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark

Take care to use mode append if you need inserting over a non-empty dataframe :

```
writeConfig = {
 "Endpoint" : "yourhostcosmosdb",
 "Masterkey" : "yourmasterkey",
 "Database" : "pruebadb",
 "Collection" : "collection1",
}
df.write.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").mode('append').options(**writeConfig).save()
```